# SQL — segment by groups

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL DB, I have a purchases table that has these columns:

```
USERID PURCHASE_AMOUNT  
3         20
9         30
3         5
4         5
1         10
1         5
```

I would like to generate a report like this

```
SUM_OF_PURCHASES_RANGE NUM_OF_USERS  
0-1                    0
1-5                    1
5-20                   1
20-30                  2
```

Where it means: there are 0 users who bought up to 1(SUM of purchases) (inclusive), there are 1 users who bought between 1 to 5 etc...

What query should I use to generate it?

Comment: is this purchase_range fix 1,5,20,30??

Comment: What would you do with a user who bought 31 items, or 81 items, or 3001 items?  Also, how do you arrive at 2 users in the range 1-5 given three entries with the purchase amount of 5 (users 3, 4, 1)?  Similarly, users 1 and 3 bought 6-20 items (not one as your sample output suggests).

Comment: Also, suppose there was an entry in the purchases table with user ID 3, amount 19; would that count as 1 or 2 users towards the count in the range 6-20?  Also, did you really mean you want the users who bought 1 item to count in both 0-1 and 1-5?

Comment: @Dk222 your question is still unclear . can you make it more proper by giving example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the range using a `UNION`, and just `LEFT JOIN` to that to get all categories; (edited for your change in the desired result)

```
SELECT CONCAT(base.lower,'-',base.upper) PURCHASE_RANGE, COUNT(userid) NUM_OF_USERS
FROM (
  SELECT 0 lower, 1 upper UNION SELECT 2, 5 UNION SELECT 6,20 UNION SELECT 21,30
) base
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT userid, SUM(purchase_amount) pa FROM purchases GROUP BY userid
) p
  ON p.pa >= base.lower AND p.pa <= base.upper
GROUP BY base.upper
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0be29/4).

Answer (score 1):

More easier syntax :

```
SELECT PURCHASE_RANGE , COUNT(*) as NUM_OF_USERS  
FROM 
(
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN PURCHASE_AMOUNT <= 1 THEN 1
    WHEN PURCHASE_AMOUNT > 1 AND PURCHASE_AMOUNT <= 5 THEN 5
    WHEN PURCHASE_AMOUNT > 5 AND PURCHASE_AMOUNT <= 10 THEN 10 
    WHEN PURCHASE_AMOUNT > 10 AND PURCHASE_AMOUNT <= 20 THEN 20
    WHEN PURCHASE_AMOUNT > 20 AND PURCHASE_AMOUNT <= 30 THEN 30 END AS PURCHASE_RANGE  
FROM Table1
) AS A
GROUP BY PURCHASE_RANGE
ORDER BY PURCHASE_RANGE
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a232f/10)

Comment: @Dk222 , is this query helpful to you ?

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear. i need SUM of purchases

Comment: do you mean sum of purchase amount ?

Comment: yes. exactly. sum of purchase amount

Comment: please don't forgot to vote up or accept this ans if it help you .

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    select PURCHASE_RANGE , NUM_OF_USERS 
 from (
 select 1 as PURCHASE_RANGE ,count(*) as  NUM_OF_USERS  from table1 where PURCHASE_AMOUNT between 0 and 1
  union all
 select 5 ,count(*) from table1 where PURCHASE_AMOUNT between 1 and 5
 union all
 select 20 ,count(*) from table1 where PURCHASE_AMOUNT between 6 and 20
  union all
 select 30 ,count(*) from table1 where PURCHASE_AMOUNT between 21 and 30
)t
```

[DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a232f/7)

Answer (score 0):

There are faster ways to do this if you need the performance (this will do a full table scan), but try this:

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_amount BETWEEN 0 AND 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0) bucket_0_to_1,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_amount BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0) bucket_1_to_5,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_amount BETWEEN 5 AND 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0) bucket_5_to_20,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_amount BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0) bucket_20_to_30,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_amount > 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0) bucket_over_30, FROM my_table LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This gives the 'wrong shape' to the result.  It gives one row with sums in each bucket, rather than 5 rows as requested.

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier if the ranges will ever change.

```
with ranges(rstart, rfinish) as (
    select  0,  1 union all
    select  2,  5 union all
    select  6, 20 union all
    select 21, 30
), purchases(amount) as (
    select sum(PURCHASE_AMOUNT)
    from <purchases_basetable> -- <-- your tablename goes here
    group by USERID
)
select
    -- concat(case when r.rstart = 0 then 0 else r.rstart-1 end, '-', r.rfinish) as SUM_OF_PURCHASES_RANGE /* op's name for the group */,
    concat(r.rstart, '-', r.rfinish) as SUM_OF_PURCHASES_RANGE /* better name for the group */,
    count(*) as NUM_OF_USERS
from
    purchases as p inner join
    ranges as r
        on p.amount between r.start and r.finish
group by r.rstart, r.rfinish
order by r.rstart, r.rfinish
```

I don't know what the mysql query plan will look like. It's trivial to change the query to use derived tables rather than table expressions. (But I include it below anyway.)

You might also find the UNPIVOT operation to be useful on a platform that supports it.

```
select
    -- concat(case when r.rstart = 0 then 0 else r.rstart-1 end, '-', r.rfinish) as SUM_OF_PURCHASES_RANGE /* op's name for the group */,
    concat(r.rstart, '-', r.rfinish) as SUM_OF_PURCHASES_RANGE /* better name for the group */,

    count(*) as NUM_OF_USERS
from
    (
        select sum(PURCHASE_AMOUNT) as amount
        from <purchases_basetable> -- <-- your tablename goes here
        group by USERID
    ) as p inner join
    (
        select  0 as rstart, 1 as rfinish union all
        select  2,  5 union all
        select  6, 20 union all
        select 21, 30
    ) as r
        on p.amount between r.start and r.finish
group by r.rstart, r.rfinish
order by r.rstart, r.rfinish
```

Comment: The ranges lower limits are incorrect; the BETWEEN AND operation includes both end points, so you need ranges 2-5, 6-20 and 21-30 (though the question is ambiguous — at best; more likely careless — on this, I now see).

Comment: The definition of ranges isn't clear in the question. Of course, it doesn't strictly matter if they overlap because they are entirely independent of each other.

Comment: Since that comment got upvoted let me clarify.
I'm fully aware the `BETWEEN` is inclusive. Since we appear to be dealing with integer values it's quite easily to define the appropriate closed intervals.

Answer (score 0):

To get the values you want in rows, you need to start with a driver table that has all the values you are interested in, and then `left outer join` to the data:

```
select driver.mina, coalesce(sum(cnt), 0) as Num_Of_Users
from (select 1 as mina, 5 as maxa union all
      select 5, 10 union all
      select 10, 20 union all
      select 20, 30 union all
      select 30, NULL
     ) driver left outer join
     (select purchase_amount, count(*) as cnt
      from purchases
      group by purchase_amount
     ) pa
     on driver.mina >= pa.purchase_amount and
        (pa.purchase_amount < driver.maxa or driver.maxa is null)
group by driver.mina
order by driver.mina
```

You can actually do this without the inner `group by`.  That is likely to reduce the size of the data significantly (especially in your example) before join.

I would encourage you to include both the lower and upper bounds of the range on each row.

Comment: I don't think your join condition will work with a maxa of null.